# mkdocs search plugin suddenly disappeared - any debugging suggestions?

Tags: mkdocs

I've been running a (company-internal) site that uses mkdocs, the materials for mkdocs them, and the default mkdocs search plugin.

It all worked fine until some point around the change of year, when the search field suddenly disapeared.. without any obvious thing having changed. The website is being served by a (company-hosted) gitlab instance.. there's no error or warning message during build that seems to relate to this issue.. nor does there seem to be any related error/warning in the javascript console. All this makes it very difficult to know where to start investigating..
Did anybody experience the same? Or do you have suggestions of where I could start looking?

best
Michael

tried to change the order in which plugins are executed, and various search plugin settings - without any effect. Looked for error/warning messages during mkdocs build (via gitlab ci-cd) and in the Javascript console - without success. Where to start?